# How do I change the default Icon of Atom editor on Windows?

Tags: icons, atom-editor

I was trying just putting the .ico file instead of the app.ico but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are on windows, try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/. The shortcut in your start menu should update automatically, but you might have to restart your computer to do so.